# Why does numpy vectorization not improve the speed of my code

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, vectorization

Here is the original code that does not use vectorize

```
import tensorflow as tf
import time
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data(
    path='mnist.npz'
)

x_train = x_train.reshape(60000,-1)
scaler = StandardScaler()
X_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(x_train)
pca = PCA()
pca = PCA(n_components = 16) # or 12      ->       3, 4  filter_size=3
X_pca = pca.fit_transform(X_scaled).reshape(60000, 4, 4, 1)
start = time.time()
X_pca_zero = X_pca[0]
for i in range(1,60000):
    X_pca_expanded = X_pca[i]
    print(tf.image.ssim(X_pca_zero, X_pca_expanded, 255, filter_size=4))
print(time.time()-start)
```

It is essentially comparing the similarity between a reference image and a set of images. I feel it can be sped up by vectorization (so as to avoid the time wasted by the for loop). Therefore, I used the numpy vectorize function -

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import time
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data(
    path='mnist.npz'
)
def my_func(x_train):
    x_train = x_train.reshape(60000,-1)
    scaler = StandardScaler()
    X_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(x_train)
    pca = PCA()
    pca = PCA(n_components = 16) # or 12      ->       3, 4  filter_size=3
    X_pca = pca.fit_transform(X_scaled).reshape(60000, 4, 4, 1)
    start = time.time()
    X_pca_zero = X_pca[0]
    for i in range(1,6000):
        X_pca_expanded = X_pca[i]
        print(tf.image.ssim(X_pca_zero, X_pca_expanded, 255, filter_size=4))
    print(time.time()-start)

    return 0
np.vectorize(my_func(x_train))
```

However, there doesn't seem to be any speed improvements.

Comment: From the `numpy` documentation: 'The [vectorize](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop.'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python function calls, arguments are evaluated before they are passed to the function.  `np.vectorize` is Python function that expects a function as argument, and returns another function.

```
np.vectorize(my_func(x_train))
```

runs `my_func(x_train)` before passing the result to `vectorize`.  That argument evaluation does all the prints and timing, and returns 0.  I doubted if it would work, but:

```
In [194]: np.vectorize(0)
Out[194]: <numpy.vectorize at 0x7ff091c36310>
```

So it does run without error, but does nothing.  All the timing is done before anything is passed to `np.vectorize`.

I suspect you read about the magic of "vectorization", and tried to use a like name function without reading its docs.  Not only did you miss the performance disclaimer, but also didn't learn how use it (it does have its uses).  It is not some sort of "compiler" or "vectorizing magic".

Most of your code is `sklearn`, while the only thing you time is

```
X_pca_zero = X_pca[0]
for i in range(1,60000):
    X_pca_expanded = X_pca[i]
    print(tf.image.ssim(X_pca_zero, X_pca_expanded, 255, filter_size=4))
```

I'm not familiar with what `tf.image.ssim` does.  But it is a tensorflow function, and may be complex.  Running it 6000 times is bound to take noticeable time.  If it doesn't let you provide all `X_pca` values at once (as opposed to one by one), there's nothing you can do speed it up.

I don't know what it returns, but usually we don't include a `print` inside a timing block. Each print call adds to the computation time.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I was not quite clear in my question. The tf.ssim does work quite fast. The only problem is that the for loop runs 60000 times. If you look at the arguments given to ssim, it is comparing a reference image to one of the 60000 images (a perfect candidate for parallelization). I was hoping that the vectorize reduces the time taken by the for loop.

Comment: What we call "vectorization" in `numpy` is not "parallelization" in the sense of running the same code on multiple machines or cores at the same time.  There are tools for doing that.  Tensorflow might even have them (under its concept of working with 'batches').